# jQuery: Instead of Alert, Fadein data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uploadify, alert

I display the data with alert in uploadify as following. However, instead of the alert, i want to print on the page instead of alert (for example jquery fadein.). How I can do that?

```
'onComplete': function(a, b, c, data, e){
            alert(data);                                
        },
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _print_? Do you mean _append_?

Comment: @Saeed Neamati, yes i mean append, something like echo in php which just appears on page, instead of alert or pop-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('<div style="height:100px; width: 200px; padding: 21px; display: none">' + data + '</div>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn()
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eR43D/